How to ensure Brahminas don't step out of line regarding the law
The Dharmashastras forbid any capital punishments on Brahminas. While this is partly understandable as doing harm to a holy man is considered wrong, couldn't some Brahminas with evil intentions step out of line and continously do wrong even in exile? I want clear answers and ones based on a realist view. So, not the simple threat of heaven and hell, but actual laws which combat this.

It is not true that a sinful Brahmin can go unpunished simply due to his birth in a religious family. Also, a repeat offender is no longer a Brahmin but a Brahma-bandhu.
Kindly refer to the below excerpt from the Mahabharata regarding Ashvatthama who was a Brahmin. I've highlighted Lord Krishna's advice to Arjuna in bold.

Arjuna dragged Aśvatthāmā before Yudhiṣṭhira and Draupadī, saying,
“Here is the killer of our sons. What should be done with him now?”
The soft-hearted Draupadī felt compassion for Aśvatthāmā, who sat with
his head down. As he was a Brahmin she folded her palms in respect and
said, “Release him, Arjuna, for he is the son of your martial teacher.
It is said that the son is one with his father, and thus it is as if
Droṇa himself were here. Indeed, Droṇa’s wife did not ascend his
funeral pyre because she had a son. Killing Aśvatthāmā will cause her,
our worshipful superior, grief and cannot be in accord with religious
principles. My lord, do not make her cry like me. Nor should we, the
kingly order, become guilty of the sin of needlessly slaying Brahmins.
Such a sin can burn the whole body of a royal family to ashes.”
Yudhiṣṭhira, approving Draupadī’s words, said, “Excellent, excellent.
O gentle lady, your words are quite in accord with the sacred
teachings of the Vedas.” Arjuna and the twins also expressed their
agreement--but not Bhīma. “We need show this man no mercy. He has
mercilessly killed sleeping men for no purpose other than his own
interests. Killing him is the only fitting punishment.”
Bhīma advanced menacingly toward Aśvatthāmā with his fists clenched.
His eyes were wide with fury and he ground his teeth. Draupadī quickly
came between him and Aśvatthāmā, who still said nothing and stared at
the ground.
Seeing the conflict, Kṛṣṇa moved forward and placed a hand on Bhīma’s
shoulder, telling him to be peaceful. Turning to Arjuna, He said, “A
Brahmin, even when guilty of sin, is not to be killed; but if he is an
aggressor, he must be killed. All these rulings are in the scriptures.
You should act accordingly. You have to fulfill your promise to your
wife, and you must also act to Bhīmasena’s satisfaction—and Mine. We
both want you to kill this culprit.”

Source: https://vedabase.io/en/library/mbk/

Please use a real MBH translation versus the abridged version. Also, wasn't he tonsured versus put to death.

Anyways I see what happened in the end. Are there other examples as well?

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/mahabharata/d/doc118463.html

Yes, he is to endure physical and mental pain for 400,000+ years (until end of Kali Yuga) which is worse than any capital pumishment. If it were any ordinary person doing the same sin, he'd have simply been killed by the Pandavas. I'm not aware of another example at this time.

Thank you very much!

I want something more generalized and this isn't as direct as I would've liked.
